# Cannot update pip on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pip

I am trying to update pip on ubuntu because it keeps telling me "You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 8.1.2 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command." but when I use that command it tells me "bash: /home/zak/.local/bin/pip: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory"

Comment: Might be better asked on the ubuntu forum http://askubuntu.com/

Comment: For the record: You should probably just ignore that message. Your version of pip is (most likely) obtained via Ubuntu's own package management. Manually updating it will just screw with the integrity of your environment. If you really need a newer version of pip, [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

If you are updating it globally (and not inside a virtualbox) try using sudo.

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```